# Learning Uboot programming

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

Please suggest methods or sources how to start uboot programming.

Comment: http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best method, meaning the one that will give you the best final understanding and insight, is to get a board with a working U-boot configuration, a JTAG debugger for that board, the source code, and dig in.  Get it working straight up, then change things and see what happens.  It is a well-maintained project, but the fundamental complexity of bootloaders (and especially a generic bootloader) make learning it a hands on kind of thing.